# Catmull Rom Spline - Constant Speed

Tags: 3d, mathematics, algorithm, software-engineering, curves

Given the equations found in the answer here:

[Determine arc-length of a Catmull-Rom spline to move at a constant speed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14985/determine-arc-length-of-a-catmull-rom-spline)

How would one A) Apply this to a 3D Catmull-Rom Spline, and B) write A out programmatically (for the math illiterate)?

Comment: The generalisation of the formulas to 3D splines is straightforward; each time you see an expression with `x` and `y`, just add a 3rd term with `z`.

Comment: @Sam You could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to move along at a constant speed along a path whose "segments" are not a constant length - and it's not trivial to make them that way.

I would approach the problem by making a "Mover" of sorts which follows a "Path".

```
public interface Path<T> {
   public T getPoint(float delta);
}
public class Mover<T> {
   public Path<T> path;
   public T position;
   public T lookahead;
   public float lookaheadDelta;
   public float delta;
   public float speed;
   public void init() { ... }
   public void update(float dt) { ... }
}
```

(sorry if you haven't learned about generics/templating, just replace T with Vector3)

Most "path" implementations like Catmull-Rom spline can give you a point given a delta value that ranges from 0 to 1. Based off of this the Mover moves along the path looking "lookaheadDelta" ahead and moving towards that point. The smaller this value the smoother the movement, but if it's too small you might make to many path calculations per update.

The update method is important, it tries to move speed*dt units along the path. If the distance between lookahead and the current position is less than this value than you need to iteratively calculate the new lookahead based on the lookaheadDelta and continually move towards it.

It would look something like this:

```
public void update(float dt) {
  float move = dt * speed; // units to move
  while (move > 0.0) {
    // between current position and target
    float room = distance( lookahead, position ); 
    // how much we're actually moving this iteration
    float actual = Math.min( move, room );
    // the normalized vector between lookahead and position
    float direction = (lookahead - position) / room; 
    // move my position accordingly
    position += direction * actual;
    // update move to be the remaining amount we need to move
    move -= actual;
    // reset target
    if (actual != room) {
      delta += lookaheadDelta;
      lookahead = path.getPoint(delta);
    }
  }
}
```

And don't forget about initializing it!

```
public void init() {  
  position = path.getPoint(0.0);
  delta = lookaheadDelta;
  lookahead = path.getPoint(delta);
}
```

Don't forget to add in logic to check when delta >= 1.0 which means you're at the end!

You could even calculate lookaheadDelta based on the estimated length of the spline and the units of your game. I would guess 100 data points would be enough making 0.01 a good value for lookaheadDelta.

You could also cache "direction" and "room" after each lookahead calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issues while attempting to solve this for a Catmull-Rom spline without access to the source code in to fetch the coefficient derivatives.

My spline was based on time parameters of 0 - 1000, but this could easily be adapted for 0 - 1.

Since the position and time do not have 1:1 ratio, tracking the difference in position of the next desired step and then adjusting the next time step accordingly gave me the uniform values I was looking for.

My basic approach was as follows:

```
        Vector nextPosition = spline.GetPointAtTime(splineTime + 1);
        Vector positionDelta = (nextPosition - position);

        float distance = positionDelta.Magnitude();

        float ratio = 1 / distance;
        splineTime = splineTime + speed * ratio;
```

Where the speed is some predefined constant. The object position is then set per frame by getting the amended spline time in the last line of the code.